# Applying clip-path to parent causes shaky animations to child elements

Tags: css, clip-path

Currently, I'm running into a weird bug with clip-path property in css. I'm applying the polygon clip path to create an angled section on this landing page I'm developing for my job. The issue is, whenever I apply clip-path, any child elements inside of this parent container that have transitions become shaky. I've toggled the property on/off and for some reason, whenever I removed the clip-path property, the animations are smooth again?

[Click to view my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cheyneosy/989ea5w3/6/)

Below is the html and css:

---

**HTML**

```
<header class="gs_hero">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="gs_hero_contents">
            <div class="gs_hero_callout">
                <h1>Getting Started</h1>
                <p>7 Steps To Setting Up Your Artwork</p>
                <button class="gs_lm_btn" id="gs_lm_btn">Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.gs_hero {
  background: url(../img/custom_journey_header.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 60%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 1600px 0, 1600px 70%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 1600px 0, 1600px 70%, 0 100%);
  transition: -webkit-clip-path 0.35s, clip-path 0.35s;
}
.gs_hero:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(130, 29, 33, 0.75);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.gs_hero_contents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.gs_hero_contents h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.gs_hero_contents p {
  font-size: 19px;
  margin: 8px auto;
}
.gs_hero_callout {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 60px auto 0;
}
.gs_lm_btn {
  background-color: rgba(236, 54, 66, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 38px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  margin: 15px auto 0;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 160px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 425ms ease, opacity 425ms ease, 
  transform 425ms ease;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 425ms ease, opacity 425ms ease, transform 
  425ms ease;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 425ms ease, opacity 425ms ease, transform 
  425ms ease;
 }
 .gs_lm_btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 33px 35px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: translateY(2px);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears to not work properly with `clip-path`, and since `clip-path` has bad browser support, one workaround could be to use `transform: skew` to create the sloped/slanted bottom

```css
/*********************************************************************
- overrides
*********************************************************************/
body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.content {
    padding: 0;
    /*min-height: 4000px;*/
}
.content-wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
/*********************************************************************
- gs hero parent
*********************************************************************/
.gs_hero {
    background: url(../img/custom_journey_header.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 60%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.gs_hero:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(130, 29, 33, 0.75);
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    top: -50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 130%;
}
/*********************************************************************
- gs hero contents
*********************************************************************/
.gs_hero_contents {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    /*margin: 10vh auto;*/
}
.gs_hero_contents h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.gs_hero_contents p {
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 8px auto;
}
.gs_hero_callout {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 60px auto 0;
}
.gs_lm_btn {
    background-color: rgba(236, 54, 66, 1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 38px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: none;
    margin: 15px auto 0;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 160px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 425ms ease, opacity 425ms ease, transform 425ms ease;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 425ms ease, opacity 425ms ease, transform 425ms ease;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 425ms ease, opacity 425ms ease, transform 425ms ease;
}
.gs_lm_btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 33px 35px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: translateY(2px);
}
```

```html
<header class="gs_hero">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <section class="gs_hero_contents">
    <div class="gs_hero_callout">
     <h1>Getting started</h1>
     <p>7 Steps To Setting Up Your Artwork</p>
     <button class="gs_lm_btn" id="gs_lm_btn">Learn More</button>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I had a gut instinct that browser support was to blame. Your code is great! I modified it a bit and it works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @cheyneosy If the answer is valuable for you, consider upvoting/accepting it